# tomcat jersey jackson ContextResolver getContext() never called

Tags: java, tomcat, jackson

I've been searching and trying different settings over the last few days with no luck.  Using Tomcat7, Jerseyv2.1, Jacksonv2.8.4 and everything seems to be working with the exception of the ContextResolver().  It initializes but the getContext() never gets called.
Below is the web.xml

```
<init-param> 
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
        <param-value>com.rest.provider,com.rest</param-value> 
</init-param> 
<init-param>
        <param-name>org.glassfish.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

Below is the ObjectMapper:

@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ObjectMapperContextResolver.class);
    static {
        logger.info("starting...");
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS);
        mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE);
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

```
}

public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
    super();
    logger.info("Init ObjectMapperContextResolver");

}

@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
    logger.info("ObjectMapperContextResolver.getContext() called with type: "+type);
    return mapper;
}
```

}

I can see "starting" and "Init ObjectMapperContextResolver" in the logs but I never see getContext() get called.  Any ideas or help on the situation would be greatly appreciated.